# In Firefox, how can I copy a tab's URL if I have already deleted the URL?

Tags: firefox

Suppose I have opened `https://www.example.com` in a Firefox tab. Then I deleted the URL from the address bar (e.g. using <kbd>Backspace</kbd>). Is there a way to get back the URL without reloading the webpage? I want to copy the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> (possibly twice) while the address bar is focused will cancel the entire editing mode and return the address bar to its normal state, showing the current page's address.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will undo just the last change to the text.

Comment:  I'm been in pain for so long. Thanks!